# Change keyboard layout with WIN key on Windows 7

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I tweaked my Linux box to use WIN key to change keyboard layout (EN/RU), howether sometimes I need to use Windows-machines and I want to have the same feature on them.

Any ideas how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows the standard keys to change keyboard layout is Left Alt + Shift. So you want to emulate those two keys basically....

One way is to use a tool to override the Win key such as [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com)

Once you install it and launch it, add the following to your script file:

```
RWin::
Lwin::
    Send {LShift Down}{LAlt Down}{LShift Up}{LAlt Up}
return
```

and reload your script.

The above will take over both of your Win keys. Remove either line starting with `RWin` - for the Right Windows key or `LWin` - for the Left, to re-enable it.

Hope that helped.

PS: I've tested this on Windows XP, should work just fine on newer versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that he just wants to switch the layout while the key is pressed, and switch it back to the standard one when the key is released so the actual Autohotkey script for achieving that looks like that:

`$Lwin::
    Send {LShift Down}{LAlt Down}{LShift Up}{LAlt Up}
    KeyWait, Lwin Send {LShift Down}{LAlt Down}{LShift Up}{LAlt Up}
return`

Tested it with Win10 and it works exactly like the Feature "Left Win (while pressed)" in the advanced KDE Keyboard settings.